# Archive mirrors for old Debian

Tags: debian, mirror

I need to install old Debian 5 on my system in order to run some tests. The installation complains regarding bad archive mirror on network. How to solve that problem? Does it means that nobody mirrors the outdated distribution?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying this URL as repo url: http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/ ?

Comment: "I need to install old Debian 5 on my system in order to run some tests. ". It might be interesting to know what tests...

Answer (score 17):

At the  *configure the package manager* step you should select (in top of the country mirror list):

```
enter information manually
```

Then select a debian mirror from [here](https://www.debian.org/distrib/archive) , for example:

```
archive.debian.org
```

Then the Debian mirror directory:

```
/debian/
```

You should ignore the next error saying :

```
security.debian.org couldn't be accessed
```

because there is no security updates for debian Lenny.

Answer (score 9):

Old releases aren’t kept on the main mirror network; you need to use http://archive.debian.org/debian/ instead.

Depending on what you’re trying to test, you might find it easier to use `debootstrap` instead:

```
wget http://archive.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/debian-archive-keyring/debian-archive-keyring_2010.08.28\~lenny1_all.deb
dpkg -x debian-archive-keyring_2010.08.28\~lenny1_all.deb lenny-keyring
sudo debootstrap --keyring=lenny-keyring/usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg lenny lenny http://archive.debian.org/debian/
```

will create a Debian 5 base installation in a `lenny` sub-directory in the current directory.

Comment: For other releases search http://archive.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/debian-archive-keyring/ for the right keyring